# Finding element using its innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Please have a look to this DOM Tree...

```
  <div>

      <div>

            <span>  Home1  </span>

      </div>

      <span>  Home2  </span>

      <span>  Home3  </span>

  </div>
```

Now suppose I have a scenario where somehow I got the innerHTML of first span **Home1**.
Is it possible to get the element span and  its parent div by using only this (Home1) information.

Comment: You can iterate through every element and compare its innerHTML with the one you're looking for? Then finding the parent is easy.

Comment: which language are you using? Or is this language agnostic?

Comment: @FelixKling _ Javascript

Comment: looping throug all the divs is a big problem. if you plan to click on that element it's easy.if you tell us what you wanna do we can give you some simple solutions.

Comment: Without an ID or a class? You'd have to use an XPATH expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are so many ways to get info about your elements.**

Using the innerHTML as an identifier is **not** a good solution.

You probably need some sort of event to that makes you search for that "Menu1"

So here is a click handler that works also on other events that give you information about what you have clicked.

```
function handler(e){
 var txt='You clicked on a '+e.target.nodeName+'\n';
    txt+='The innerHTML is '+e.target.innerHTML+'\n';
    txt+='The text is '+e.target.textContent+'\n';
    txt+='The parentNode is '+e.target.parentNode.nodeName+'\n';
 alert(txt)
}
document.addEventListener('click',handler,false)
```

**DEMO**

```js
function handler(e) {
  var txt = 'You clicked on a ' + e.target.nodeName + '\n';
  txt += 'The innerHTML is ' + e.target.innerHTML + '\n';
  txt += 'The text is ' + e.target.textContent + '\n';
  txt += 'The parentNode is ' + e.target.parentNode.nodeName + '\n';
  alert(txt)
}

document.addEventListener('click', handler, false)
```

```html
<div>
  <div><span>Menu1</span></div><span>Menu2</span><span>Menu3</span>
</div>
```

If you want that your script searches for that "Menu1" you should consider adding that "Menu1" as an attribute on the span or parentNode.

```
<div id="Menu1">
 <span>Home1</span>
</div>
```

and then call

```
document.getElementById('Menu1');
```

Which is very fast.

Answer (score 12):

[Here is what you want](http://richard2001.blogspot.com/2010/02/select-elements-by-innerhtml-with.html).

Here is html:

```
<label>opal fruits</label>
```

Here is jQuery:

```
$("label:contains(opal fruits)")
```

Comment: What made you think the OP uses jQuery?

Comment: Yeah well, you couldn't have known that beforehand :P Answers to questions without library tags should at least contain a solution without libraries.

Comment: @FelixKling there was no tag wen I posted the answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
var mySpans = document.getElementsByTagName(span);

for(var i=0;i<mySpans.length;i++){

if(mySpans[i].innerHTML == 'Home1'){

var parent = mySpans[i].parentNode;
break;

}

}
```

this selects the `parent` of span having `innerHTML` Home1

Answer (score 4):

`innerHTML` method return String type. It don't associate with DOM tree.

You can use jQuery and it `contains` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVG8M/)):

```
$(":contains('Home1')").last()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var divRef;  //Reference to the container of your div / span elements
var spans = divRef.getElementsByTagName("span");
var spanContainer;

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
    if(spans[i].innerHtml == "Home 1"){
        spanContainer = spans[i].parentNode;
        break;
    }
}

if(spanContainer){
    alert("Element has been found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findNodeByInnerHTML(nodelist, innerHTML){
    for(let ii = 0; ii < nodelist.length; ii++){
        if(nodelist[ii].innerHTML === innerHTML)
            return nodelist[ii]
    }
}
let span = findNodeByInnerHTML(document.querySelectorAll('span'), 'home')
```